# Extraer resultado de consulta

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Estoy intentando extraer el resultado de la consulta para almacenarlo e usarlo fuera de la consulta y no hacer múltiples consultas pero no me guarda el valor en la variable.

La variable la registra como undefined es decir se queda vacía a la hora de leer la variable fuera, pero dentro de la consulta si que está guardada sin problema.

```js
// Declaro la variable.
var guardar;

// Realizo la consulta.
Consulta.find({tipo: "2"}, (err, res) =>  {
  guardar = res[0].body; console.log(guardar); // Muestra la información
});

// Fuera de la consulta.
console.log(guardar); // Undefined
```

Estuve haciéndolo con findOne y era el mismo resultado, haber si me podéis echar un cable en como puedo extraer la variable para usarlo más adelante sin hacer la consulta de nuevo.

Comment: Prueba realizando un `return` a _guardar_, o asignando la consulta a una nueva variable => `const result = consulta.find(...)`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRiverame devuelve el mismo resultado Undefined tanto en un return como haciendo const la consulta y llamándola

Comment: Puede ser un problema de sincronía entonces... que es Consulta? Puedes incluir la declaración por favor

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera es un require extrayendo el model : const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Consultando = mongoose.Schema({
  tipo: String,
  body: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Consultas', Consultando);

Comment: Revisa si [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189365/async-await-in-nodejs-mongoose) te sirve

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ese lo estuve viendo antes pero es para reflejarlo en la página la información en ningún momento la guarda y estuve viendo otros resultados async y nada algo estaré haciendo mal.

Comment: Que el ejemplo este reflejando o no el dato, es algo sin importancia, porque si te percatas, esta guardando la información en una variable _esperando_ la respuesta con `async/await`. Probaste dejando tu método asíncrono?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera cómo lo hago , algo estoy haciendo mal y me da error de async.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118905/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-jose).